# Make google spreadsheet chart use tab+column name as the series header

Tags: google-sheets

I have a chart of two series, `Sheet1!Foo` and `Sheet2!Foo`. They are named in the chart the same way - `Foo`. How can I include the sheet name in the series name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A chart is based on the data contained in the Data Range from which it is created, and nothing else. Sheet name is not a part of the picture. In order for sheet name to appear within the chart, it has to appear in the header row/column within chart's range. This can be done automatically by a script or a custom function, but with two sheets, it's far easier to rename the headers manually.